# how to make a diagonal for a matrix equal to another natrix diagonal?

Tags: matlab

i want to get this: if

```
 a=1 2 3
 4 5 6
 7 8 9 i   want a at the end to be

                                  a= 1  6  9
                                  12 25 18
                                  49 24 81
```

> which mean the diagonal i did it in square also the opposite diagonal
>   and the other elemnts in the matrix i multpplied them with 3.. so i
>   have this so far :

```
a=rand(n)
c=fliplr(diag(diag(a)).^2)+(tril(a,-1)+triu(a,1)*3)
i=(diag(diag(fliplr(a)))).^2
c(1:n+1:n^2)=0
result=fliplr(c+i)
```

> this works if i do it in a comand window but i want to write it as a
>   function!  thanks in advance.

Comment: Your formating is a bit crazy, consider [edit]ing the post properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A shorter and computationally faster alternative to using logical indexing would be to use element-wise multiplication and element-wise powers.

```
% function b = myfun(a)
n = 10000
a = randi(10,n);
I = eye(size(a,1),'logical');
b = a.^2.*I + a.*3.*~I;
% end
```

Answer (score 1):

it's easier to use logical indexing. if you want to use it as a function just open a new file with `function A = myfunc(A)`

```
% random matrix
n = 5;
A = randi(10,n);
% here you can do:
% function A = myfunc(A)

% diagonal indexes
diagIdxs1 = eye(size(A),'logical');
diagIdxs2 = fliplr(diagIdxs1);
diagIdxs = diagIdxs1 | diagIdxs2;
% do operations on diagonals and on non-diagonals
A(diagIdxs) = A(diagIdxs).^2;
A(~diagIdxs) = A(~diagIdxs).*3;
```

Comment: if i put what i wrote in a function it will not work bacause of the line c(1:n+1:n^2)=0 and thats my problem !